# Adding jars to classpath using gradle

Tags: compilation, jar, classpath, gradle

In gradle, is there a way to reference external jars. I have some external jars, sitting in another folder outside the project structure. Is there a way to add a reference to these jars in my build.gradle file, so that they are picked up during the compilation process?

Thanks

Edit:

I modified mu build.gradle with an allprojects task having the following 'sub-tasks(?)' as follows:

```groovy
repositories{
   flatDir name:'ExternalJars',dirs:'<path to the jars>'
   dependencies{
      compile: 'jarname:jarname:version'
   }
}
```

This seems to make my build run just fine. Can someone shed some light on what exactly is happenning when I create the repository and specify the dependencies? - Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The basic idea is that it looks for jar files in the root directory(s) you specified in `flatDir` that match `[artifact]-[version].[ext]` pattern.

Note: artifact group is ignored (so you can specify them as `:jarname:version`), and also all artifacts assumed to have no transitive dependencies.

By the way, another way to reference local jars is to create a local ivy repository. You'll need to use this if you want to declare transitive dependencies.